# create object based on time in c++

Tags: c++, oop, time, simulation

i am writing a simulation about vehicle manufacturing, i am wondering how i can create objects based on time..

i have a base class Vehicle, and children Motorbike, Car, and Truck.
1 Motorbike will be manufactured every 1 hour,
1 car will be manufactured every 3 hours,
and 1 truck will be manufactured every 8 hours.

how can i create those objects according to the time indicated?

thanks

Comment: You are referring to simulation time? If so, how are you driving the simulation? Are you using fixed time increments, elapsed real-time times `N`, ...?

Comment: i am using real time, but later on i want to speed up the time, let say 1 month in the program = 10 minute real time

Comment: And do all productions start and end at a fixed multiple of a basic time unit (e.g. `C * 1h`)? Or at arbitrary points?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to have a thread dedicated to each task, that just sits in a loop of <strike>lather, rinse,</strike>create, sleep, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can create timers and wait on those timer events.
When the timer expires you can create corresponding object. 
You can monitor this in a thread.

When will you be destroying these objects?

Comment: the manufactured vehicle will go to some processes then they will be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have complete control over the timing (say, you can increment the time irrespective of the system timer), then you'll need to implement that as a class. Then provide a Singleton or static function to return the Current time. The time class should be copyable so that objects can remember the starting time. Also, provide a function for advancing time by a certain amount, and for doing time comparisons.

Inside each manufacturable object (or better, the factories that manufacture them), add two functions:

1. `StartManufacture`. This function should remember the starting time.
2. `CheckManufactureComplete`. This function fetches the current time, and checks if the required waiting time has elapsed since manufacturing started.